# send fixed data with a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to send some data from a page in my website to another page. 
i figure i should use a html form then set action attribute to destination.

```
<form method="POST" action="/destination">
     <input type="text" name="item-wear">FACTORY-NEW</input>
     <button type="submit">Sell</button>
</form>
```

i tried to swap input tag to div but it doesn't work as i thought. 
also i don't want to use hidden input as the other questions answered in Stackoverflow. because i guess users can change data from browser and i don't want that.

ps. sorry for bad english any edit is appreciate.

Comment: People can change the data no matter if you use a hidden input or something else. Don't rely on users not tampering with the data.

Comment: @doorstuck yeah i know. any idea what is the best way to prevent that?

Comment: Dont trust anything that comes from the user. I don't know what you are trying to solve. But don't blindly use the input from the user since he can be evil. I cannot answer since I don't know what you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could secure your form with "token" and use the `$_SESSION` to pass your data outside of the form :

```
<?php

session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
$_SESSION['secret_data'] = "Top secret data";

?>

<form method="POST" action="/destination">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="item-wear">FACTORY-NEW</input>
    <button> type="submit">فروش</button>
</form>
```

And then, just check if the token matches with the session one. If yes, get the data you saved from the `$_SESSION` array.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "readonly" attibute prevent users from changing your input

```
<input type="text" name="item-wear" readonly>FACTORY-NEW</input>
```

Or you can use select

```
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

but as [doorstuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639292/doorstuck) says, you'll still need to verify this data at back-end.

Answer (score 1):

You can give fixed value like this..

```
<form method="POST" action="/destination">
     <input type="text" name="item-wear" value="Enter your fixed value here">
     <input type="submit" value="فروش">
</form>
```

Hope this will help you!!!